# Logic error in my defined Mutex class and the way I use it in producer consumer program - pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads, producer-consumer

I have added a Mutex class to adhere to RAII. I am not sure if the way I am using it is correct.

After the queue is locked by a producer, the program unexpectedly finishes.

**MutexClass.h**

```
#ifndef MUTEXCLASS
#define MUTEXCLASS

#include <pthread.h>

class MutexClass
{
private:
    pthread_mutex_t & _mutexVariable;
public:
    MutexClass (pthread_mutex_t &);
    ~MutexClass ();
};

#endif // MUTEXCLASS
```

**MutexClass.cpp**

```
#include "mutexClass.h"
#include <stdexcept>

MutexClass::MutexClass (pthread_mutex_t & arg) : _mutexVariable (arg)
{
    _mutexVariable  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    int returnValue = pthread_mutex_lock (&_mutexVariable);
    if (returnValue > 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error ("Mutex couldn't be locked!");
    }
}

MutexClass::~MutexClass()
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&_mutexVariable);
}
```

This is the **main.cpp** where I am using the object of the above defined mutex class.

***Qt's classes are here for the namesake because I am Qt Creator. Please ignore them.***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

#include "mutexClass.h"

pthread_mutex_t mutexVariable;
pthread_cond_t  conditionVariable;

int numberOfActiveProducers;
int numberOfActiveConsumers;

QList <int> sharedQueueA;
QList <int> sharedQueueB;

/*
 * Shared queues are supposed to be shared among four threads. Two producer, and two consumer threads.
 * Producer threads will put the 1's in it, and Consumer threads will remove the 1's.
 * Assumption: `sharedQueue` can contain only 10 elements at a time.
 */

int sizeOfSharedQueue;

void checkForSpaceAndPush (QList <int> & argList, int listId, pthread_t argTId)
{
    std::cerr << "\nQueue " << listId << ", First check by Producer: " << argTId;
    if (argList.length () < sizeOfSharedQueue + 1)
    {
        {
            MutexClass mutex1 (mutexVariable);

            std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", Locked by Producer: " << argTId;

            if (argList.length () < sizeOfSharedQueue + 1)
            {
                argList.push_back (1); std::cerr << "\nPushed by Producer " << argTId << ": " << "Length of queue " << listId << " is: " << argList.length ();
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "\nProducer " << argTId << ". Queue " << listId << " is full. Length of queue is: " << argList.length ();
                pthread_cond_wait (&conditionVariable, &mutexVariable);
            }
        }
        std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", UnLocked by Producer: " << argTId;
    }
}

void checkForSpaceAndPop (QList <int> & argList, int listId, pthread_t argTId)
{
    std::cerr << "\nQueue " << listId << ", First check by Consumer: " << argTId;
    if (argList.length () > 0)
    {
        {
            MutexClass mutex1 (mutexVariable);
            std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", Locked by Consumer: " << argTId;

            if (argList.length () > 0)
            {
                argList.pop_front (); std::cerr << "\nRemoved by Consumer: " << argTId << ", Length of queue " << listId << " is: " << argList.length ();
            }
            else
            {
                pthread_cond_signal (&conditionVariable); std::cerr << "\nSignal issued by Consumer: " << argTId << ", Length of queue " << listId << " is: " << argList.length ();
            }
        }

        std::cerr << "\n\nQueue " << listId << ", UnLocked by Consumer: " << argTId;
    }
}

//  This function is run by the `Producer` threads.
void *producerThreadFunction (void *arg)
{
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self(); std::cerr << "\nProducers: " << tId; std::cerr.flush();
        checkForSpaceAndPush (sharedQueueA, 1, tId);
        checkForSpaceAndPush (sharedQueueB, 2, tId);
    }

    return NULL;
}

//  This function is run by the `Consumer` threads.
void *consumerThreadFunction (void *arg)
{
    Q_UNUSED (arg);

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_t tId = pthread_self (); std::cerr << "\nConsumer: " << tId; std::cerr.flush();
        checkForSpaceAndPop (sharedQueueA, 1, tId);
        checkForSpaceAndPop (sharedQueueB, 2, tId);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    numberOfActiveProducers = 2;
    numberOfActiveConsumers = 2;
    sizeOfSharedQueue       = 10;

    // Producer threads creation
    pthread_t producerA;
    pthread_t producerB;

    if (pthread_create (&producerA, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer A\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&producerB, NULL, producerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Producer B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Consumer threads creation
    pthread_t consumerA;
    pthread_t consumerB;

    if (pthread_create (&consumerA, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer A\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pthread_create (&consumerB, NULL, consumerThreadFunction, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error creating thread Consumer B\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Joining every thread
    if (pthread_join (producerA, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer A\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (producerB, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Producer B\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (consumerB, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer B\n");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pthread_join (consumerA, NULL)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error joining thread Consumer A\n");
        return 2;
    }

    QApplication a (argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show ();

    return a.exec ();
}
```

**Output is here:**

```
...  
...  

Queue 140388157085440
Removed by Consumer: 1403881570854401403881654781442
Queue , Locked by Consumer: 1140388148692736
Removed by Consumer: , Length of queue 1 is: , First check by Producer: 140388148692736, Length of queue 2 is: 1403881654781449

Queue 

Queue 2, UnLocked by Consumer: 140388148692736
Consumer: 9

Queue 1, UnLocked by Consumer: 140388157085440
Queue 2, First check by Consumer: 1403881570854401140388148692736
Queue 1, First check by Consumer: 140388148692736

Queue , Locked by Producer: 

Queue 2, Locked by Consumer: 140388157085440
Removed by Consumer: 1403881654781441, Locked by Consumer: 140388148692736
Pushed by Producer 140388165478144: Length of queue 1 is: 10

Queue 1, UnLocked by Producer: 140388165478144
Queue 2, First check by Producer: 140388165478144

Queue 2, Locked by Producer: 140388165478144The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Also, notice the following part of output:

> Queue 2, Locked by Consumer: 140388157085440
>   Removed by Consumer: 1403881654781441, Locked by Consumer: 140388148692736

I have created only 2 consumers  but the pids shown here are 3. Why is that so?

Comment: There are a few problems with this code, but I'm wondering: why aren't you using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` from the C++ thread library? They would take care of all of the minute details of pthread-interaction for you.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger I have written this for learning sake. I don't want any library functions to help right now. I will use them when I know what i am doing.

Comment: "Qt's classes are here for the namesake because I am Qt Creator. Please ignore them." No. *You* are supposed to first extract a minimal example. That said, the way you pass around references(!) to your mutex class is plainly asking for trouble, it defies any kind of encapsulation. Please also study the so-called "Law of Three" and some existing threading libraries like e.g. Boost's or your C++11 compiler's. BTW: Check out the `friend` keyword. It allows you to encapsulate mutex and event tightly and only provide access to their internals in a single function to wait.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt `You are supposed to first extract a minimal example.` You mean I should write the program in emacs? How are Qt's classes making a difference here? `the way you pass around references(!) to your mutex class is plainly asking for trouble,` I request you to write an answer explaining the problem and its solution (currently) without Boost library.

Comment: I don't care how you edit your code, but the Stack Overflow guidelines demand that you extract a minimal example that everyone can use to reproduce your problem. Also, superfluous code distracts the reader (and writer) from the actual issue. Stripping any unnecessary stuff that Qt Creator inserted is your job therefore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you initialize `mutexVariable` to `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` every time you create a new construct a new `MutexClass`. Consider what happens if thread A holds the `mutexVariable` and thread B wants to acquire the mutex:

```
thread A tries to lock mutexVariable and succeeds
    mutexVariable = PTHRAED_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutexVariable)

thread B tries to lock mutexVariable and succeeds
    // this assignment overwrites the locked state thread A has stored
    mutexVariable = PTHRAED_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
    // mutex is default-initialized (not locked) - so lock it
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutexVariable)
    // both threads now believe they have the mutex
    // and all syncronization is lost

thread B unlocks mutexVariable
    // succeeds

thread A unlocks mutexVariable
    // uh.. it is not even locked any more?!
```

You should initialize `mutexVariable` only once, in `main.cpp:13`:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexVariable = PTHRAED_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

and remove the initialization from `MutexClass`.

Not sure if this will fix all of your issues, but that's the thing I'd do first.

Comment: thanks, well, at least that problem is solved. What are the other problems that you were talking about?

Comment: E.g. constructor not explicit, plus the things Ulrich Eckhardt mentioned. On a more general note, using pthread directly is not going to bring you enlightenment. Use std::mutex and friends, but *understand* what is going on under the covers. And "under the covers" does not mean pthread-level, it means CPU/memory-level. The pthread library is an unfortunate implementation detail.

Comment: thanks for following up. BTW, I don't quite get it why people are against pthreads. How would I have know about the your solution if I had used some high level library which would have automatically taken care of all the details. ? Why is this learning not necessary?

Comment: To become a farmer, you have to understand plowing. Why to plow, when to plow, and how to do so. But today, you shouldn't spend time learning how to make an ox pull your wooden plow. We don't use oxen and wooden plows any more, we have tractors with metal plows. -- What you learned in this question is a detail of pthreads, std::mutex won't even let you make this mistake! You'll still eventually need a deeper understanding, but that lies in the CPU/memory/caching/reordering, not in pthreads.

Comment: you also disagree that it was worth while to learn about rule of thirds which Ulrich pointed out? You think I would have learnt about that rule with boost library? Not trying to argue here. I just want to learn programming!